# Does a word being a noun change on context?

Tags: grammar, nouns, syntactic-analysis

In *Dulce Et Decorum Est* by Wilfred Owen, there are double-noun pairs which I believe are syntactically wrong:

> Bent double, like old beggars under sacks,
>   **Knock-kneed**, coughing like hags, we cursed through sludge,
>   ...
>   If you could hear, at every jolt, the blood
>   Come gargling from the **froth-corrupted** lungs,
>   ...

Am I right?

Comment: FYI, "knee" is a noun or a verb, but "kneed" is a verb or (as in this case) a part of a compound adjective.  And both "corrupt" and "corrupted" can function as verbs or adjectives -- not a noun.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that the two examples you cite are double noun pairs. ["Knock-kneed"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knock-kneed) is a compound word used as an adjective describing the condition of a person's legs. And in like manner, "froth-corrupted" is a compound word that aptly describes the lungs for a person suffering from certain respiratory conditions, such as advanced emphysema.

Comment: What about "Knock-kneed, coughing like hags". Strictly speaking, is it syntactically correct to write "knock-kneed, coughing" ? I don't think so

Comment: The second phrase "like old beggars under sacks",  colors the phrase "Bent double". However, "knock-kneed" and "coughing like hags" are independent (there could have been one group of others than "we" who were coughing like hags, but not knock-kneed, and a different group who were knock-kneed but not coughing). Except for the second phrase, the phrases before "we" are (to me) a list of descriptive items that apply to "we". I see no syntactical error, though if I were writing that passage, I would have used different punctuation-perhaps even none at all-for the comma after "double".